# Trouble Uploading Person Accounts Into Salesforce Using Apex Data Loader

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to import ~15k `PersonAccounts` into Salesforce using the Apex Data Loader version 25.0.1 available [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader).

I have already called Salesforce and enabled `PersonAccounts` on my `Organizaion`. I have successfully logged in with my admin credentials and exported a `RecordType` csv showing the following info:

```
ID                  | NAME              | DEVELOPERNAME
01280000000Lsy4AAC  | Person Account    | PersonAccount
01280000000LsxzAAC  | Business Account  | Business_Account
```

I have created a new csv with the following columns:

```
RECORDTYPEID
LASTNAME
FIRSTNAME
DESCRIPTION
PERSONMAILINGSTREET
PERSONMAILINGCITY
PERSONMAILINGSTATE
PERSONMAILINGPOSTALCODE
PERSONMAILINGCOUNTRY
PERSONHOMEPHONE
PERSONEMAIL
```

and specified `01280000000Lsy4AAC` for all records in the `RECORDTYPEID` column.

When I attempt to insert my csv I get the same error for all rows:

```
Record Type ID: id value not valid for the users profile: 01280000000Lsy4AAC
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I upload `PersonAccounts` using the Apex Data Loader?

**Update:** I have tried the method recommended [here](http://salesforcevision.blogspot.com/2011/07/importing-person-accounts-into.html) of getting the `RecordTypeID` from the query string of the web interface (which gives you the same `RecordTypeID` without the "ACC" suffix and I still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to enable Person Accounts on my Sys Admin profile

Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles -> System Administrator, then Object Settings, then Account, and make sure Person record type is assigned.

https://sites.secure.force.com/success/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000duV6EAI